# In a simple choice game, how do I limit options to a list?

Tags: c

Basically I'm trying to get the user’s choice. If the user enters any option other than those specified by the Outlook menu, the code should display the following message (with X replaced by the actual character entered by the user):

```
Invalid choice for outlook: 'X'
Valid options are '1', '2', and '3'.
```

I am trying to do this in C, and I can only use these 2 header files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

I am creating a Multiple Choice / Choice game using C, different outcomes based on the options selected from the lists.

Comment: Note that header files such as `<stdio.h>` are not libraries — they're header files or headers.

Comment: Do you know about `switch` statements? Or `if/else if`? What is it specifically that you don't know how to do? Would be good to show what code you have so far - e.g. how you have read in the choice.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do the range of valid options vary depending on which question is asked, or are there only 3 valid choices for every question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The first Is 3 valid choices, but there are 2 more choices based on what the user chooses and they both have 2 Valid choices not 3

Comment: @machine_1 I need to limit the user to only choosing options (numbers 1 ,2 ,3 ) from the list otherwise it will come up with an error message stating the number they used and that it's not a valid option and gives them the valid options

Comment: Edit the extra information into the question, and it would be a good idea to show what you've tried so far, too, along with an explanation of why it isn't adequate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch statement. I beleive that would be better for creating an interactive UI in C.

```
printf("1. A \n 2. B \n 3.C");
printf("\n\nInsert your option : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
switch(n)
          {
              case 1: //code for option 1
                      break;
              case 2: //code for option 2
                      break;
              case 3: //code for option 3
                      break;
              default:
                      printf("invalid choice for outlook: %d", n);
             }
```

The code will display  valid three options as

> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. C
>
> Insert your option :

Based on your input, the rest of your code works. For example if you input 1 , switch statement will execute code corresponding to the case 1 and after that once it encounter break, it terminates execution. Thus it wont move to next option. This will happen in case of option 2 or 3. If you insert other values (invalid values) , it will print 
" invalid choice for outlook: " mesage with the value append to the end

[Refer for doubts](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-cc/)